# TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit'

Tags: javascript, undefined

> [2017-12-05 23:15:02.546] [ERROR] default - TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
>       at Query._callback (/home/Bot/cf.js:5206:59)
>       at Query.Sequence.end (/home/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:86:24)
>       at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/home/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:137:8)
>       at Query.EofPacket (/home/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:121:8)
>       at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
>       at Parser.write (/home/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:75:12)
>       at Protocol.write (/home/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
>       at Socket. (/home/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)

and the code line 5206 is

```
function newBalance(hash)
{
  pool.query('SELECT balance FROM users WHERE hash = ' + pool.escape(hash), function(err, row) {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(row.length == 0) return;

    steamIDCsrf[hash]['balance'] = row[0].balance;
    var balanta = steamIDCsrf[hash]['balance'];
    var steamid = steamIDCsrf[hash]['steamid'];

    if(socketBySteam.hasOwnProperty(steamid))
    {
      io.sockets.connected[socketBySteam[steamid]['info']].emit('message', {
        type: 'balance',
        new: balanta
      });
    }
  });
}
```

line 5206 is `io.sockets.connected[socketBySteam[steamid]['info']].emit('message', {`

Comment: I think `connected[socketBySteam[steamid]['info']]` is giving you undefined. If not, debug the code and check which one of `io.sockets.connected[socketBySteam[steamid]['info']]` is giving you undefined.

Comment: what should i need to correct in this code ?